# Blender won't start anymore after cleaning up my OS with the Display Driver Uninstaller (DDU) after switching graphics cards

Tags: error

My Blender worked fine until today. I suspect that it has something to do with me cleaning my OS and deleting old drivers and programs. I used DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) to get rid of my old AMD Graphics Driver because I bought a new Graphics Card a while ago (NVDIA GEFORCE GTX 1060). I updated all my drivers and now Blender won't start anymore. When I click the Blender icon the program window with only grey in it pops up and my "loading cursor" keeps loading infinitely. When I try to press buttons I get the message "Blender.exe has stopped working".

Things I already tried:

- Reinstalling Blender
- Downloading the "opengl32.dll" for 64bit systems and putting it into the Blender folder
- Trying to start the program in the directory instead of the shortcut

Nothing helped so far. Does anyone know what went wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: There are a so many similar questions with answers that you should try..

Comment: well, I came up with the things I tried by googling the issue and they didnt work, so I was hoping somone knew what to do

Comment: Have you tried disabling your graphics card and just use your cpu to start blender?

Comment: @WhatAMesh I just disabled my graphics card and used my onboard device and this is what I get when I start blender.
https://imgur.com/oZikg3z

Comment: Does no one really know what I can do? I really want to continue learning blender but I dont see how I can fix my problem. :(